# How do I make Apache Cayenne respect database defaults?

Tags: java, orm, apache-cayenne

I have a postgres database with some defaults such as:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id serial,
    name text,
    created_at DEFAULT now(),
    price numeric DEFAULT 9.99
);
```

How do I make Cayenne honour those defaults when I do a `context.newObject(Product.class)`?

Currently I am hooking into the `onPostAdd` callback and then setting my defaults there, though I was wondering if that's the only way to do it? Can't I use my database defaults somehow to keep it [`DRY`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)?

I am using Apache Cayenne 4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `onPostAdd` is your best bet. This is object-relational impedance at its worst. As one of Cayenne authors I am well aware of this issue. Wish there was a DRY solution.

Comment: No worries. I have created a [gist that does pickup default values](https://gist.github.com/gurpreet-/8062ba4fff9e43797ecc40bc4852e74d), at the expense of extra queries. Thanks for Cayenne, it's great!